# react-router RouterContext deployment error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router, server-rendering

I'm struggling to make my universal React web app run on the server (OpenShift). I developed other universal apps before, but never encountered this error:

[image: React renderToString() invariant violation]

Basically, when running on the server the **RouterContext** passed to ReactDOM.**renderToString**() is not recognized as a valid React Element.

Digging deeper inside renderToString implementation, on localhost I have this value for the **RouterContext** context type:

[image: localhost routercontext type]

But on the server I got this:

[image: production routercontext type]

And that's why React is raising an invariant violation when trying to create the RouterContext element.